# numpy - create polynomial by its roots

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a `numpy.polynomial` by the roots of the polynomial.

I could only find a way to do that by the polynomial's a's

The way it works now, for the polynomial `x^2 - 3x + 2` I can create it like that:

`poly1d([1, -3, 2])`

I want to create it by its roots, which are `-1, -2`

Comment: The solution to your problem is not unique. The same roots lead to an infinity of polynomials.

Comment: It becomes unique if another point is defined. In that case, Lagrange or Newton methods can be used (and already exist in scipy interpolate)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I know but I thought the OP asked only for solutions using only the roots. But yes using a quadrature method allows this.

Comment: my poly looks like this (x-A)(x-B)(x-C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy has a function that does this: [`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfromroots)

Note that

> If a zero has multiplicity n, then it must appear in roots n times.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Sure you don't want `np.polynomial.Polynomial.fromroots`, which is very similar but returns a `Polynomial` object?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you will need to implement the multiplication of polynomial, that is, you need to make sure your product is able to generate the product of

**(am * x^m + ... + a0) * (bn * x^n + ... + b0)**

If your product is able to do this, then knowing the roots of

**r1, ..., rk**

You can write this as

**(x - r1) * ... * (x - rk)**

and you need to repeatedly calculate the product here.